Why I can't see my gameobject's prefab game object in unity in scene view?
As You Can See Here
indeed it has materials and other needed things to see it but unfortunately you can't. In This image I selected chassis so you could see any problems in inspector if there are some

well as you only shared the top object its unclear... but theres no meshrenderer there to have a visible object, you sure the renderers are switched on?

You can open 2nd Image and see that there is a mesh rendered and it's checked.

FIXED!
Deleted and reimported prefab and its meshes.
